# Return only the number before a space

Tags: php, regex

I use the `preg_match` php function to only take the number before a whitespace dash and another whitespace ( - ).

All my subjects have a number and then a small description afterwards like this;

> 3546425 - Small Description

I need only the number;

> 3546425

I have tried this expression but it returns only a single value; 1

> /([0-9])(.+?(?= - ))/

This is my php code;

```
$pattern = '/([0-9])(.+?(?= - ))/';
$subject = '3546425 - Small description';

echo preg_match($pattern, $subject);
```

I can use the subtr function of php, but that number before the first space isn't always the same length, it can be shorter or longer as well and then it won't work.

Can somebody explain what's wrong? Because I've tested it [here](http://regexr.com/) and there it highlights the entire number just like I want it.

Comment: What about [`explode(" - ", $s)[0]`](https://ideone.com/2o2z9N) since you know there is a number at the beginning of all the strings you have? A regex would be better if the string format were unknown.

Comment: The problem is that preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.[SOURCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Problems here :

1) preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred. So if you echo preg_match the value will be 0 or 1 [SOURCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

2)  you need to add an output parameter($matches), $matches is an array of match so you need to echo a match in this array !

```
$pattern = '/([0-9])(.+?(?= - ))/';
$subject = '3546425 - Small description';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

[ONLINE EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb3edc5f45a83ae5da21fd05c3fd4fb8cf5a6cc9)

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer! I see there are other simpler ways to do it as well. But I understand now way it return a 1 and that I have to use the `$matches` as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it really easy and your string always starts with the number, you can just typecast it:

```
$string = "3546425 - Small Description";
$number = intval($string);
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `(\d+)` (there is space at the end) and then take element at the 1 group.

You can check this regex at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

[image]

Comment: You do not need any capturing groups here as the match value is in Group 0. Just `\d+` is enough with `preg_match`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew group 0 matches the number and space at the end. But Mentos93 needs just the number.

Comment: (\d+) also display only a one (1).

Comment: `^\d+` without space should satisfy you all : no need to match the space, and the whole result is the expected number.

Comment: @Aaron your approach will also work. My approach is more generic.

Comment: How is any of those approach more generic? One assume the number is at the start of the text, while the other assume it is followed by a space. Anyway you're right that my solution isn't better. It's up to OP to decide which of these conditions is the most guaranteed, and whether what happens when it is not matched is problematic or not.